# Radial Basis Function Network

Tags: neural-networks

I have a problem in this code: Error using plot
Vectors must be the same length.
plot(t,ge);

```
 t=-1:1/20:1;              % time period
 ge=0.4*cos(4*x).*exp(-0.5*x);     % exact fucntion
```

Comment: Why are you passing $x$ as a parameter and not $t$?

Comment: Yes, you are right I make a mistake. Now it is working thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 t=-1:1/20:1;              % time period
 ge=0.4*cos(4*t).*exp(-0.5*t);     % exact function
 plot(t,ge);
```